# Show that $2^{84} \pmod{377} \equiv 1 $

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, prime-factorization

$\varphi(377)=336$ and $gcd(377,2)=1$ so $2^{336} \equiv1\pmod{334}$

$84\cdot4=336$

I know that:\begin{cases} & 2^{84}\pmod{13}\Rightarrow2^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{13}\Rightarrow2^{84}\equiv 1\pmod{13}\\
  &2^{84}\pmod{29}\Rightarrow2^{28}\equiv 1\pmod{13}\Rightarrow2^{84}\equiv 1\pmod{29}\end{cases}

How do I make the link to: $2^{84} \pmod{377}$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: If a divides c and b divides c and gcd(a,b)= 1 then a*b divides c.

Comment: $$a,b\mid c\iff \text{lcm}(a,b)\mid c$$

Bill Dubuque calls this a universal property of lcm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees that there is exactly one $x$ satisfying $x\equiv 1 \mod 29$ and $x\equiv 1 \mod 13$ so since $1$ satisfies, you are done.

Comment: So,can I use CRT for every exercise with composite modulus ?

Comment: Yes you just have to make sure your factors are coprime. Also you won't need it everywhere for example mod 10 is easy to deal with without CRT.

Answer (score 1):

The Chinese remainder theorem says that $2^{84}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ and $2^{84}\equiv 1\pmod{29}$ together implies $2^{84}\equiv 1\pmod{337}$.